Open media player on PLAY button
I have a keyboard with PLAY button, and headset with media controls also. My SO is a Windows 11.
All commands works well, start play, pause play, volume adjust, FF, etc. But play commands only works if media player is already open.
My question is: How to use play buttons to opens media player and start music?

Obs. media player is correctly associated with mp3 files, and set as default in audio files types and link types of:

MS-MEDIA-PLAYER
MS-PLAYTO-AUDIO
MSWINDOWSMUSIC

Obs2. link type DLNA-PLAYSINGLE is associated with Legacy Media Player, but I can't changed it.

You can probably write an AutoHotkey script that listens for Media_Play_Pause keyboard events and runs your media player if it's not already running. For details, see https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm, https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/KeyList.htm#multimedia, https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/ProcessExist.htm, and https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Run.htm.
